# UIKit _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler + 36 : Occurred occasionally from Crashlytics Report

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, crashlytics, mbprogresshud

I got this crash report from Crashlytics

```
UIKit   _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler + 36
```

And it just happened only one time from total users of my app and I have never seen this crash before when it is in debug version.

From searching ,it is related to too many "release" but my project is actually using ARCs and all of the 3rd party module ,they are all ARCs . Only one module I found that still have non-ARC is MBProgressHUD .But it call "release" in dealloc() and with #ifdef  !_has_feature(obj_arc)  . So the release should not be called at all . Here is the code

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [self unregisterFromNotifications];
    [self unregisterFromKVO];
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
    [color release];
    [indicator release];
    [label release];
    [detailsLabel release];
    [labelText release];
    [detailsLabelText release];
    [graceTimer release];
    [minShowTimer release];
    [showStarted release];
    [customView release];
    [labelFont release];
    [labelColor release];
    [detailsLabelFont release];
    [detailsLabelColor release];
#if NS_BLOCKS_AVAILABLE
    [completionBlock release];
#endif
    [super dealloc];
#endif
}
```

Can I conclude that this crash is just randomly happened ? Because non of my code call "release" (my app still has a relatively small-user base)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I also have same issue. But still couldn't find the solution. May the the problem arises related to release of delegates.
Did you already resolve it ???

Comment: I have about 20 of these in production. No leads yet.

Comment: I have only 1 of this and the person who had is was hacking the in app purchase buying, so maybe a rooted device?